# Deployment vue project on server with git remote and githook

Tags: git, vue.js

I would like to deploy a vue project from my computer to a remote server (test server. Later, on production server).
Below, i wrote elements to make my deployment.
I don't know if i used the best practice.
I have some questions (at the end of this text).

steps :

- on my computer : push code (the dev branch because i push on test server) on remote server
- on server : pull the code (or clone ? i don't know the code copied in the "vueproject01" folder)
- on server : a githook script (post-receive) triggered : npm install, npm run build, copy the dist folder generated to /var/www/html/vueproject01

test server :

```sh
toto@dev_server1:~$ mkdir /home/toto/vue/vueproject01
toto@dev_server1:~$ cd /home/toto/vue/vueproject01
toto@dev_server1:/~/vue/vueproject01$ git init
Dépôt Git vide initialisé dans /home/toto/vue/vueproject01/.git/
toto@dev_server1:/~/vue/vueproject01/.git$ cd hooks/
toto@dev_server1:/~/vue/vueproject01/.git/hooks$ vim post-update
toto@dev_server1:/~/vue/vueproject01/.git/hooks$ cat post-update
#/bin/bash
echo "START DEPLOYMENT..."
rm -rf ./dist
npm install
npm run build
rm -rf /var/www/html/vueproject01/*
cp -r ./dist/* /var/www/html/vueproject01
echo "END DEPLOYMENT"
```

my computer :

```sh
git remote add dev_server1 toto@ipdevserver1:/home/toto/vue/vueproject01
git push dev_server1 dev
Enumerating objects: 245, done.
Counting objects: 100% (245/245), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (242/242), done.
Writing objects: 100% (245/245), 739.18 KiB | 1.83 MiB/s, done.
Total 245 (delta 150), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Résolution des deltas: 100% (150/150), fait.
remote: START DEPLOYMENT ...
remote: /home/toto/vue/vueproject01
remote: npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/toto/vue/vueproject01/package.json'
remote: npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
remote: npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/toto/vue/vueproject01/package.json'
remote:
remote: up to date in 0.346s
remote: found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote: npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! syscall open
remote: npm ERR! path /home/toto/vue/vueproject01/package.json
remote: npm ERR! errno -2
remote: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/toto/vue/vueproject01/package.json'
remote: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote: npm ERR! enoent
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /home/toto/.npm/_logs/2021-05-20T18_48_49_375Z-debug.log
remote: cp: impossible d'évaluer './dist/*': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
remote: END DEPLOYMENT
```

**[OK]** - on server : pull the code (or clone ? i don't know the code copied in the "vueproject01" folder)

**[ERROR]**- on server : a githook script (post-receive) triggered : npm install (no such file or directory, open '/home/toto/vue/vueproject01/package.json')

The next statements can't run correctly.

On my computer, i push the dev branch.
On test server, it pulls the dev branch, but in the folder, the dev branch doesn't exist and it must be on master branch.
Then, the folder is empty (except .git), so, "npm install" statement crash because it doesn't find "package.json".

How must i prepare my destination folder ?
Is it the best practice to deploy vue project with git push on remote server ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but: Git makes a terrible deployment system. If at all possible, don't use Git as a deployment mechanism. What I don't have here is any advice on what *to* use.

Comment: Thanks Torek for your advice.
What do you do to production for your vue apps ?

Comment: I have no vue apps. I did do some small degree of deployment with Git about ten years ago; we wrote our own scripts.

Comment: Respect ! it's you the master (of GIT).
I read a great response on SO from you on an another question.
I understand and i'm going to reflect with coworkers to improve this part (idea with scripts, well noted ! scripts with ssh surely).
Thanks again torek.